# How can you add a many to many field in Wagtail Admin?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to set make a footer for a Wagtail site that is included on every page, but I want to include a list of links (phone, email, social media). If I try the code below without the `panel = [...]` I can see it sort of works, but I am unable to add any items:

[image]

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from django import forms

class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    CONTACT_CHOICES = (
        ('fas fa-phone', 'Phone'),
        ('fas fa-envelope', 'Email'),
        ('fab fa-facebook-f', 'Facebook'),
        ('fa-instagram', 'Instagram'),
        ('fab fa-linkedin', 'LinkedIn'),
        ('fab fa-twitter', 'Twitter'),
        ('fab fa-pinterest', 'Pinterest'),
        ('fab fa-github', 'GitHub'),
        ('fab fa-gitlab', 'GitLab'),
    )

    contact_type = models.CharField(choices=CONTACT_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    contact_info = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.contact_type == 'Phone':
            self.info_prefix = 'tel:'
        elif self.contact_type == 'Email':
            self.info_prefix = 'mailto:'
        else:
            self.info_prefix = ''


@register_setting
class Contact(BaseSetting):
    contact = models.ManyToManyField(ContactInfo)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('contact', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    ]
```

Is there a to add items to the M2M field? Is there a way to make lists of items in the Wagtail settings? Is there an easier way to make a footer that automatically is rendered on every page?

Comment: Use ModelAdmin to add `ContactInfo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `ContactInfo` item (presumably) belongs to a single `Contact`, so this is a one-to-many relation rather than many-to-many. (A many-to-many relation in this case would mean that you have a shared pool of `ContactInfo` items previously defined through some other view, and you're selecting which ones to attach to the current `Contact`.)

In Wagtail, this would be defined using a `ParentalKey` on `ContactInfo` to point to the corresponding `Contact`, and rendered with an `InlinePanel`. (See the [gallery image](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#images) example from the Wagtail tutorial for an example.)

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class ContactInfo(Orderable):
    CONTACT_CHOICES = (
        # ...
    )

    contact = ParentalKey('Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contact_links')
    contact_type = models.CharField(choices=CONTACT_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    contact_info = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # info_prefix handling omitted here for brevity

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('contact_type'),
        FieldPanel('contact_info'),
    ]


@register_setting
class Contact(BaseSetting, ClusterableModel):
    panels = [
        InlinePanel('contact_links', label="Contact")
    ]
```

Comment: That makes sense. I don't know why I was thinking M2M. Your answer reminded me of a blog post I found that, at the time, didn't make sense to me (just started wagtail), but with the context of your answer it makes sense.  https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail/

Comment: I just had a chance to try it and it works if I change the Contact model to:

class Contact(BaseSetting, ClusterableModel):